# how to write text inside a rectangle in R

Tags: r, text, plot, label, rectangles

I want each rectangle to contain a number, so that the first plotted rectangle would contain : rect 1 the second rect 2 and so on, but i don't know how to insert text inside rectangles.

```
require(grDevices)
## set up the plot region:

plot(c(0, 250), c(0, 250), type = "n",
     main = "Exercise 1: R-Tree Index Question C")

rect(0.0,0.0,40.0,35.0, , text= "transparent")
rect(10.0,210.0,45.0,230.0)
rect(170.0,50.0,240.0,150.0)
rect(75.0,110.0,125.0,125.0)
rect(50.0,130.0,65.0,160.0)
rect(15.0,140.0,30.0,150.0)
rect(100.0,50.0,130.0,90.0)
rect(150.0,40.0,155.0,60.0)
rect(52.0,80.0,75.0,90.0)
rect(62.0,65.0,85.0,75.0)
rect(20.0,75.0,25.0,80.0)
rect(30.0,40.0,50.0,80.0)
rect(102.0,155.0,113.0,217.0)



par(op)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the other answers mention, you can use the coordinates that you give to `rect` to place the text somewhere relative.

```
plot(c(0, 250), c(0, 250), type = "n",
     main = "Exercise 1: R-Tree Index Question C")
rect(0.0,0.0,40.0,35.0)
center <- c(mean(c(0, 40)), mean(c(0, 35)))
text(center[1], center[2], labels = 'hi')
```

You can easily put this into a function to save yourself some typing/errors

```
recttext <- function(xl, yb, xr, yt, text, rectArgs = NULL, textArgs = NULL) {
  center <- c(mean(c(xl, xr)), mean(c(yb, yt)))
  do.call('rect', c(list(xleft = xl, ybottom = yb, xright = xr, ytop = yt), rectArgs))
  do.call('text', c(list(x = center[1], y = center[2], labels = text), textArgs))
}
```

Use it like this

```
recttext(50, 0, 100, 35, 'hello',
         rectArgs = list(col = 'red', lty = 'dashed'),
         textArgs = list(col = 'blue', cex = 1.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
text( (0.0+40.0)/2, (0.0+35.0)/2 , 'transparent')
```

where we chose x,y to be the centroid of your rectangle. You could define a function to draw the `rect` then place the `text` at its centroid.

Note: these coords are large; this will display outside your normal view. So you'll either need to zoom to see it, or scale coords to the range 0.0..1.0

By the way, read [12.2 Low-level plotting commands](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Low_002dlevel-plotting-commands)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `text()` as a separate graphics call.

```
coords <- matrix(
c(0.0,0.0,40.0,35.0,
    10.0,210.0,45.0,230.0,
    170.0,50.0,240.0,150.0,
    75.0,110.0,125.0,125.0,
    50.0,130.0,65.0,160.0,
    15.0,140.0,30.0,150.0,
    100.0,50.0,130.0,90.0,
    150.0,40.0,155.0,60.0,
    52.0,80.0,75.0,90.0,
    62.0,65.0,85.0,75.0,
    20.0,75.0,25.0,80.0,
    30.0,40.0,50.0,80.0,
    102.0,155.0,113.0,217.0),
ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)

 plot(c(0, 250), c(0, 250), type = "n",
         main = "Exercise 1: R-Tree Index Question C")
rfun <- function(x,i) {
    do.call(rect,as.list(x))
}
apply(coords,1,rfun)
text((coords[,1]+coords[,3])/2,
     (coords[,2]+coords[,4])/2,
     seq(nrow(coords)))
```